Why doesn't window.localStorage conserve my saved objects when a new HTML page is loaded?
Based on what I have read and understood so far from MDN JavaScript documentation, in particular, the Storage: setItem() method section, it seems that it is possible to transfer objects between two HTML pages, for example, by clicking on a link in the first page redirecting the user to the other page, provided that before saving the object we wish to transfer from the first page to the second, that object is converted to a string via JSON.stringify (I mean, if it is not already a string).
My environment:
OS : Windows 11 (64 bits)
Microsoft Edge version : 126.0.2592.61 (64 bits)
Firefox version : 115.12.0esr (64 bits)

I'm going to indicate below, my test case so that you might be able to reproduce easily the problem that I've encountered by simply a copy/paste of the contents of the following files which you need to put somewhere on your computer but in the same directory:
file1.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr-FR">
  <head>
    <title>File1</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
     function saveObject() {
         const myObj = {
             key1: "value_01",
             key2: "value_02"
         };
         window.localStorage.setItem(
             "mySavedObj",
             JSON.stringify(myObj)
         );
     }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="saveObject();">
    <p>Saving the object in file1.html</p>
  </body>
</html>

file2.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr-FR">
  <head>
    <title>File2</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script type="text/javascript">
     function loadObject() {
         const loadedObj = JSON.parse(
             window.localStorage.getItem("mySavedObj")
         );
         objStr = JSON.stringify(loadedObj);
         console.log(`Object loaded successfully : ${objStr}`);
     }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="loadObject();">
    <p>Loading the object in file2.html</p>
  </body>
</html>

So, what is the problem?

If I run the above-mentioned programs using Microsoft Edge, that is, opening first, file1.html and then opening file2.html, I get the expected result without any problem via the Console of the browser's Inspect element. The message Object loaded successfully : {"key1":"value_01","key2":"value_02"} is printed. Moreover, after file2.html has been loaded, if I write window.localStorage in the console and then hit the Enter, I have the following content which is printed in the console : Storage {mySavedObj : '{"key1":"value_01", "key2":"value_02"}, length: 1}. This shows clearly that my object was conserved going from file1.html to file2.html.

But if I do exactly the same thing using Firefox, I get Object loaded successfully : null printed on the console. And when I check the content of window.localStorage I get Storage { length: 0 } as the result. So the localStorage is completly empty as if I hadn't saved any object!


Any idea about the problem that I encounter when I run the same program in Firefox?

I use Firefox exclusively, and have never had an issue with localStorage not working correctly - are you loading the file using http://? https://? or file:// - based on your question, I guess it's file:// ... so, that will NOT work in Firefox

Thank you very much for your help. Yes, I work locally, so I load my files using file://. Therefore, Firefox is apparently a dead end in this regard.

Based on your question, it's clear that you are loading the files directly from the operating system (i.e. file:// protocol)
According to documentation

In all current browsers, localStorage seems to return a different object for each file: URL. In other words, each file: URL seems to have its own unique local-storage area....

However, that is wrong, it seems at least Chrome (and other Chrome based browsers, like Edge) do NOT behave that way
This is not a bug - localStorage behaviour is undefined when using file:// protocol to show a web page - so, the fact that Edge and Firefox behave differently is not surprising.
Referring back to the above mentioned documentation

For documents loaded from file: URLs (that is, files opened in the browser directly from the user's local filesystem, rather than being served from a web server) the requirements for localStorage behavior are undefined and may vary among different browsers

(emphasis mine)

Thank you very much for your time and your help. Yes, I work locally, so I load my files using file://. Therefore, Firefox is apparently a dead end in this regard. Given that I don't have a web server at my disposal, in order to continue working locally via file://, I think the most feasible way, though not very clean, is to merge both files into one and to put the content of each of them inside a .... Then I'll have to play with the visibility attributes of those  elements via CSS to give the user the impression of having two different screens while he/she is in the same page.

@user17911 - web server at my disposal - you don't need a full blown server for what you want to do

I noticed that so long as it is the same page window.localStorage.setItemallows to save items even for local HTML opened files (file://). And it is possible to retrieve those values later with window.localStorage.getItem. However, it is not possible to find them using browser's Storage Inspect. So I imagin, again, this is also related to the fact that Firefox treats file:// differently. But as I said, given that those values seem however to persist, where and how are they stored? Inside a clear text file on the hard disk ?
